# Computing recursively defined string

Tags: c, string

> A series of strings are defined recursively as follows:
>
> > **Level 1:** S<sub>1</sub> = 'OuQ'
> >
> > **Level k:** S<sub>k</sub> = 'O' + S<sub>k-1</sub> + 'u' + S<sub>k-1</sub> + 'Q'
>
> For example, S<sub>2</sub> = 'O' + S<sub>1</sub> + 'u' + S<sub>1</sub> + 'Q' = 'OOuQuOuQQ'.
>
> Given 3 integers k, l, and r, find all the characters of S<sub>k</sub>[l], S<sub>k</sub>[l+1], ..., S<sub>k</sub>[r−1], S<sub>k</sub>[r] (where 0<k<50, and l<r)

I tried solving this problem with pointers and recursion, but it did not work because the strings are too long for reasonable computation. My code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int k,l,r;
    char icon[2000],*p;
    p=icon;

    scanf("%d %d %d",&k,&l,&r);
    OuQ(&icon,k);

    int i;
    for(i=l;i<r+1;i++){
        printf("%c",*(p+i));
    }
    return 0;
}

void OuQ(char *icon,int k){
    if(k==1){
        *(icon)='O';
        *(icon+1)='u';
        *(icon+2)='Q';
        return;
    }else{
        *icon='O';
        OuQ(icon+1,k-1);
        *(icon+4)='u';
        OuQ(icon+5,k-1);
        *(icon+8)='Q';
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `m` for? Do not see it in the "equation".

Comment: @Eraklon I typed wrongly !  Thank you

Comment: What does the `[l]` in `Sk[l]` (and similar for `l+1`...`r`) mean? The `l`th character? What should happen if the string does not have enough characters for `l` or `r`?

Comment: @Bodo: I think it selects a character from the string. The proper subscript (lowered baseline and size) denotes which string, and the bracketed subscript denotes a character from the string.

Comment: While the problem says the strings are defined recursively, that does not mean you need to use recursion to find the desired characters. Certainly you do not want to use recursion to construct the whole string. The length of the string more than doubles at each level, since each level includes the preceding string twice and adds three characters. So, when k is 49, there would be more than 2\*\*49 characters, more than you can hold in memory.

Comment: @willy Thanks for the explanation. I always wanted to know what I get when I press the L key without SHIFT. ;-) Eric Postpischil's assumption seems to fit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I would not dare to print it either ;-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil : Even if don't use recursion , I still can't find some regular for this question :(

Comment: It sounds like @EricPostpischil has an answer ready for you, so I'll just comment that a general method for finding character n of string k is as follows: 1. Return 'O', 'u' or 'Q' if n corresponds to the first, middle or last character of the string. 2. Otherwise, (a) if n is in the first half of the string, return the (n-1)th character of the (k-1)th string, or (b) if n is in the second half of the string, return the (n-(L+1)/2)th character of the (k-1)th string (where L is the length of string S_k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a non-recursive solution. Since `l` and `r` may be large, I changed them to `uint64_t`.

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


//  OuQ(k, p) returns the character at position p in S[k].
static char OuQ(int k, uint64_t p)
{
    //  Find the length of S[k-1], treating S[0] as the empty string.
    uint64_t l = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < k; ++i)
        l = 2*l + 3;

    /*  Identify where p is in O S[k-1] u S[k-1] Q.  If it is one of the
        terminal letters, return that.  Otherwise, adjust p to the position
        within S[k-1], then reduce the problem to that (by adjusting l), and
        repeat.
    */
    while (1)
    {
        if (p < 1)
            return 'O';
        else if (p < 1+l)
            p -= 1;
        else if (p < 1+l+1)
            return 'u';
        else if (p < 1+l+1+l)
            p -= 1+l+1;
        else
            return 'Q';
        l = (l-3)/2;
    }
}


int main()
{
    /*  uint64_t is used for l and r, since they may be large.  SCNu64 is
        defined in <inttypes.h> and provides a conversion specifier for
        uint64_t.
    */
    int k;
    uint64_t l, r;
    scanf("%d%" SCNu64 "%" SCNu64, &k, &l, &r);

    for (uint64_t i = l; i <= r; ++i)
        putchar(OuQ(k, i));
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: One more last question , why to use 'static' char ?

Comment: @willy: If a function (or any identifier) does not need to be used outside the current source file, there is no benefit in making it external, and there could be costs: Somebody might use the same name for a different thing in another file, and that can break the program. It is the same as limiting scope: Make names only as visible as they need to be, to reduce opportunities for errors.

Comment: OK!! I got it. Thank you.